# How to run a python script from HTML in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, flask, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension and I want to run a python script which is in my PC on click of a button from an extension (which is basically HTML). The python script uses selenium web-driver to scrape data from a website and store it in another log file.

Comment: See [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: Can u please explain how to go about it? I'm not able to comprehend.

Comment: Inspect the code of the demo extension and demo host app in that documentation, I think it's quite trivial. Or try finding a tutorial that you like more.

Answer (score 7):

You basically use [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). It allows you to create a communication bridge between your extension and an external process (such as python).

The way [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) works is by installing a *host* on your machine, and communicates to and from Chrome extension through stdin and stdout. For example:

## Host in Python

This is how you write your [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) host in python, I have included the full example of this from the docs, but made it easier to understand with less code.

#### host.py

This is basically an echo server, respects stdin and stdout, makes sure it sends it as binary stream.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import struct
import sys
import os, msvcrt

# Set the I/O to O_BINARY to avoid modifications from input/output streams.
msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)

# Helper function that sends a message to the webapp.
def send_message(message):
   # Write message size.
  sys.stdout.write(struct.pack('I', len(message)))
  # Write the message itself.
  sys.stdout.write(message)
  sys.stdout.flush()

# Thread that reads messages from the webapp.
def read_thread_func():
  message_number = 0
  while 1:
    # Read the message length (first 4 bytes).
    text_length_bytes = sys.stdin.read(4)

    if len(text_length_bytes) == 0:
      sys.exit(0)

    # Unpack message length as 4 byte integer.
    text_length = struct.unpack('i', text_length_bytes)[0]

    # Read the text (JSON object) of the message.
    text = sys.stdin.read(text_length).decode('utf-8')

    send_message('{"echo": %s}' % text)


def Main():
    read_thread_func()
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  Main()
```

## host.json

This defines the communication python host, make sure the extension guid is the guid of your extension.

```
{
  "name": "com.google.chrome.example.echo",
  "description": "Chrome Native Messaging API Example Host",
  "path": "host.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/"
  ]
}
```

#### host.bat

This runs the python executable.

```
@echo off
python "%~dp0/host.py" %*
```

#### install_host.bat

You run this once, to register your host in your OS.

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.google.chrome.example.echo" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0host.json" /f
```

## Chrome Extension

#### manifest.json

Add the permissions for `nativeMessing`

```
{
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ]
}
```

#### communication.js

In order to connect to the python host, you need to do the following:

```
const hostName = "com.google.chrome.example.echo";
let port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
```

To send a message to your python host, just send a json object to the port.

```
const message = {"text": "Hello World"};
if (port) {
    port.postMessage(message);
}
```

To know the error when it disconnects:

```
function onDisconnected() {
  port = null;
  console.error(`Failed to connect: "${chrome.runtime.lastError.message}"`);
}
```

This full example is in the docs, I just renamed some stuff for clarity, available for Windows/Unix https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging

Answer (score 0):

Th other option instead of using nativeMessaging is to use `pyodide` or `pyscript`

### Pyodide:

Install:

`npm i pyodide`

Import:

```
const { loadPyodide } = require("pyodide");
```

Use:

```
async function main() {
  let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
  // Pyodide is now ready to use...
  console.log(pyodide.runPython(`
    import sys
    sys.version
  `));
};
main();
```